# How to properly pass the data to a dio post request?

Tags: flutter, rest, dart, http, dio

I have a problem where anything I pass in the `data` of a `post` request in `dio` is not being received or is null. But I checked and printed in and it has values. I tried the link in postman but the request goes through nicely. I tried many ways like `json.encode,` `jsonEncode`, `FormData.fromMap()`, or even just the manual and hard coded way of data inpu like `{'first_name': 'sample',...}`. I used the same toJson() method in the http request and it works fine but when I used it in dio it returns error 400

here is the dio function:

```
Future<User?> registerUser({required User user}) async {
    User? retrievedUser;

    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post(
        'http://localhost/api/v1/index.php/registration',
        data:  user.toJson(), // THIS RETURNS STATUS CODE 400 AND IS SAID TO BE NULL
        // I TRIED:
        // user.toJson()
        // jsonEncode(user.toJson())
        // json.encode(user.toJson())
        // FormData.fromMap(user.toJson())
        // FormData.fromMap(json.encode(user.toJson()))
        // I tried even the manual way like {'first_name': 'sample',...}
        // i also enclosed it in json encode but still the same error

      );

      print('User created: ${response.data}');

      retrievedUser = User.fromJson(response.data);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error creating user: $e');
    }

    return retrievedUser;
  }
```

Here is how I use the function:

```
               FilledButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    User userInfo = User(
                      firstName: firstNameController.text,
                      lastName: lastNameController.text,
                      birthday: birthdayController.text,
                      gender: genderController.text,
                      mobile: mobileController.text,
                    );

                    User? retrievedUser = await registerUser(user: userInfo);

                    print(retrievedUser);
                    // if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {

                    // }

                    // Navigator.push(
                    //   context,
                    //   MaterialPageRoute(
                    //     builder: (context) => const Login(),
                    //   ),
                    // );
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    'Register',
                  ),
                ),
```

For extra information here is the model I use now it is with JsonSerializable but it still doesn't work for me:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class User {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String birthday;
  String gender;
  String mobile;

  User(
      {required this.firstName,
      required this.lastName,
      required this.birthday,
      required this.gender,
      required this.mobile});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);
}


// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'user.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

User _$UserFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
      firstName: json['first_name'] as String,
      lastName: json['last_name'] as String,
      birthday: json['birthday'] as String,
      gender: json['gender'] as String,
      mobile: json['mobile'] as String,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$UserToJson(User instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'first_name': instance.firstName,
      'last_name': instance.lastName,
      'birthday': instance.birthday,
      'gender': instance.gender,
      'mobile': instance.mobile,
    };
```

Here is the api docs:

```
$app->post('/registration', function () use  ($app){
    //Required Parameters
    verifyRequiredParams(array('first_name','last_name','birthday','gender','mobile'));
    
    //includes
    $database = new Database();
    $conn = $database->getConnection();
    
    //
    $db = new SaveInfo($conn);
    
    $response = array();
    
    $first_name = $app->request->post('first_name');
    $last_name = $app->request->post('last_name');
    $birthday = $app->request->post('birthday');
    $gender = $app->request->post('gender');
    $mobile = $app->request->post('mobile');
    

    $result = $db->savePersonalInfo($first_name,$last_name,$birthday,$gender,$mobile);
    
    if($result){
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['message'] = "Successfully Registered";
    }
    else{
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Failed to register";
    }
    echoResponse(200,$response);
});
```

Here is the working postman request

[image: postman]

Here are also the errors and the variable user that it has indeed values inside:

[image: Error1]

[image: Error2]

Is there anything wrong with how I use the dio function or with how I pass the data? I tried printing user.toJson() with and without jsonEncode and the data is fine and in json form also. I cannot find what is wrong with my code.

last additional info, here is the previous model that I used that works with http post request but does not work when I used it in dio:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class RegistrationInfo {
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? birthday;
  String? gender;
  String? mobile;

  RegistrationInfo(
      {required this.firstName,
      required this.lastName,
      required this.birthday,
      required this.gender,
      required this.mobile});

  RegistrationInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    birthday = json['birthday'];
    gender = json['gender'];
    mobile = json['mobile'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['first_name'] = firstName;
    data['last_name'] = lastName;
    data['birthday'] = birthday;
    data['gender'] = gender;
    data['mobile'] = mobile;
    return data;
  }
}
```

And here is the http post request

```
Future<int> checkUser(String firstName, String lastName) async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'http://localhost/api/v1/index.php/checkUserExist?first_name=$firstName&last_name=$lastName');
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);

      userInfo = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return response.statusCode;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      return 400;
    }
  }
```

Here is my whole code for the Registration screen:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../models/user.dart';

class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  const Register({super.key});

  @override
  State<Register> createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  final _dio = Dio(
    BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: 'http://localhost/api/v1/index.php',
    ),
  );

  final firstNameController = TextEditingController();
  final lastNameController = TextEditingController();
  final birthdayController = TextEditingController();
  final genderController = TextEditingController();
  final mobileController = TextEditingController();

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  // Future<void> registerUser(RegistrationInfo registrationInfo) async {
  //   // print(registrationInfo.first_name);
  //   // print(registrationInfo.last_name);
  //   // print(registrationInfo.birthday);
  //   // print(registrationInfo.gender);
  //   // print(registrationInfo.mobile);
  //   debugPrint(jsonEncode(registrationInfo.toJson()));
  //   debugPrint(registrationInfo.toJson().toString());
  //   try {
  //     final response = await dio.post(
  //       'http://localhost/api/v1/index.php/registration',
  //       data: json.encode(registrationInfo.toJson()),
  //     );
  //     debugPrint(response.data.toString());
  //   } catch (e) {
  //     print(e);
  //   }
  // }

  Future<User?> registerUser({required User user}) async {
    User? retrievedUser;
    print(user.toJson());
    try {
      Response response = await _dio.post(
        '/registration',
        data: user
            .toJson(), // THIS RETURNS STATUS CODE 400 AND IS SAID TO BE NULL
        // I TRIED:
        // user.toJson()
        // jsonEncode(user.toJson())
        // json.encode(user.toJson())
        // FormData.fromMap(user.toJson())
        // FormData.fromMap(json.encode(user.toJson()))
        // I tried even the manual way like {'first_name': 'sample',...}
        // i also enclosed it in json encode but still the same error
      );

      print('User created: ${response.data}');

      retrievedUser = User.fromJson(response.data);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error creating user: $e');
    }

    return retrievedUser;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                    //ENTER USERNAME
                    child: TextFormField(
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                      validator: (value) => value == null || value.isEmpty
                          ? 'Please enter some text'
                          : null,
                      controller: firstNameController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        hintText: 'Enter your first name',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                    //ENTER PASSWORD
                    child: TextFormField(
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                      validator: (value) => value == null || value.isEmpty
                          ? 'Please enter some text'
                          : null,
                      controller: lastNameController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        hintText: 'Enter your last name',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                    //REENTER PASSWORD
                    child: TextFormField(
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                      validator: (value) => value == null || value.isEmpty
                          ? 'Please enter some text'
                          : null,
                      controller: birthdayController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        hintText: 'Enter your birthday',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                    //REENTER PASSWORD
                    child: TextFormField(
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                      validator: (value) => value == null || value.isEmpty
                          ? 'Please enter some text'
                          : null,
                      controller: genderController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        hintText: 'Enter your gender',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                    //REENTER PASSWORD
                    child: TextFormField(
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                      validator: (value) => value == null || value.isEmpty
                          ? 'Please enter some text'
                          : null,
                      controller: mobileController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        hintText: 'Enter your mobile number',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 50),
              //CONFIRM REGISTER BUTTON
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 300,
                height: 50,
                child: FilledButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    User userInfo = User(
                      first_name: firstNameController.text,
                      last_name: lastNameController.text,
                      birthday: birthdayController.text,
                      gender: genderController.text,
                      mobile: mobileController.text,
                    );

                    User? retrievedUser = await registerUser(user: userInfo);

                    print(retrievedUser);
                    // if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {

                    // }

                    // Navigator.push(
                    //   context,
                    //   MaterialPageRoute(
                    //     builder: (context) => const Login(),
                    //   ),
                    // );
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    'Register',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you print what is exactly in `user.toJson()` right before you try to call the post method with Dio?

Comment: @PeterKoltai here is the value of `user.toJson()` when printed `{first_name: SAMPLE, last_name: SAMPLE, birthday: SAMPLE, gender: SAMPLE, mobile: SAMPLE}` I inputted SAMPLE in all the textformfield.

Comment: If I look at your `Postman` request, the parameters there are set as form data. But you wrote you tried `FormData.fromMap(user.toJson())`. As far as I know this should work.

Comment: @PeterKoltai yes that's what I think too but it says its null

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you remove everything from the PHP script and leave only `var_dump($app->request->post('first_name'));`? Maybe the values are there but `verifyRequiredParams` does not find them when posted with Dio?

Comment: Have you tried to pass a JSON object in Postman?